# Magento 1.7 : How to use sales_order_payment_capture event?

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, sales-order

In Magento 1.7, I want to do like after credit memo create product quantity should be deduct.

How to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sales_order_invoice_save_after` to deduct product quantity after generate credit memo :

Create **config.xml** for define event and module :

> app/code/local/RH/StockDeduct/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <RH_StockDeduct>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </RH_StockDeduct>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <RH_StockDeduct_order_invoice_save_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>RH_StockDeduct_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>decreaseqty</method>
                    </RH_StockDeduct_order_invoice_save_after>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Create **Observer.php** file for add code for deduct qty after credit memo generate :

> app/code/local/RH/StockDeduct/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class RH_StockDeduct_Model_Observer {
    public function decreaseqty(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        try {
            $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
            $invoiceItems = $invoice->getAllItems();
            foreach ($invoiceItems as $item) {
                $productId = $item->getProductId();
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                $stockItem = (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
                $sku = $product->getSku();
                $qty = $stockItem - $item->getQty();
                $product->getStockItem()->setData('qty', $qty)->save();
            }
            return $this;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! It's working like charm !!